# What Intent is triggered by clicking the notification after an app is installed by the Market?

Tags: android, google-play

What are the details of the Intent that is triggered when the user clicks on the notification created by Android Market after a new app is installed? Is it LAUNCHER or MAIN or something else? I am asking because my app is a Service not an Activity (it is a keyboard) so it doesn't need a LAUNCHER handler. However I want to display a welcome message when they click it, so I need to make sure I'm handling the right Intent. Do I need to handle LAUNCHER or MAIN or what?

Thanks in advance,
Barry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the standard one:

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

If you want to display a welcome message but also have no app icon then you might be able to register a BroadcastReceiver with that intent filter and then start your welcome screen from that (maybe launch a URL or actually include an Activity that shows the welcome info?).

Let me know if that works.